# base href not working when refreshing view in angular application

Tags: angular, visual-studio, href

In my angular application I'm changing the base URL to "/beta/" as on the server we will be putting the code to the beta folder and we need a beta with our URL
so the base href looks like this

```
<base href="/beta/">
```

When the application loads the URL looks like this.

```
http://localhost:11962/beta/login
```

So beta gets added.Further, every other page also loads after login.For example

```
http://localhost:11962/beta/profile
http://localhost:11962/beta/settings
```

But when I refresh a specific page or type the URL to load a particular route for example profile the pages stop loading.
The URL becomes

```
http://localhost:11962/beta/beta/profile
```

beta gets added on every refresh.

App-routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },        
    { path:'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
    { path:'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]
```

Login is a separate module so it has a routing module of its own

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,           
        data: { title: 'Login' }
    },
    {
        path: 'forgotPassword',
        component: ForgotPasswordComponent,
        data: { title: 'Forgot Password' }
    }
];
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: can up update the question with your app.routing file?

Comment: Updated with routing details